# Difference between encodeURL and encodeRedirectURL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) for `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` is a little vague on the difference between what rules `encodeURL` and `encodeRedirectURL` follow, are there any examples of what those exact rules are? When will the output of `encodeURL` differ from `encodeRedirectURL`?

For a concrete example, I am already generating a redirect url that I will use with `response.sendRedirect(url)`. I get that url already encoded, but I want to add a parameter to it which has a value that is another url:

```
param2=http://google.com
```

Which of the two functions do I use to encode this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`encodeURL()` is used for all URLs in a servlet's output. 
It helps session ids to be encoded with the URL.

`encodeRedirectURL()` is used with res.sendRedirect only. It is also used for encoding session ids with URL but only while redirecting.

Comment: When will the output of encodeURL differ from encodeRedirectURL?

Answer (score 21):

Salam Alekom Abduallah,
I looked and looked for an answer I knew I would find it in either stackoverflow or coderanch and there I found the [answer](http://www.coderanch.com/t/177771/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/encodeURL-encodeRedirectURL) from Charles Lyons the author of the book in my hand right now it was a cheerful coincidence.

> posted 8/9/2008 11:41 AM
>   Exactly - the difference being that encodeURL always writes the
>   session ID into the URL (if required e.g. because cookies are
>   disabled), while encodeRedirectURL contains additional logic to
>   determine if it is desirable to write the session ID in. It is a
>   really bad idea to give foreign websites the session ID for example,
>   since then they could impersonate your user's session. Hence
>   encodeRedirectURL will only put the jsessionid on the URL if that URL
>   lies within the current Web application, and not perform any rewriting
>   otherwise.

Charles Lyons (SCJP 1.4, April 2003; SCJP 5, Dec 2006; SCWCD 1.4b, April 2004) 
Author of OCEJWCD Study Companion for Oracle Exam 1Z0-899 (ISBN 0955160340)

also I found this [answer](http://www.coderanch.com/t/171910/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/encodeURL-encodeRedirectURL) too which was posted earlier,

> posted 4/19/2006 8:02 AM   Quote  Report post to moderator Hi,
>
> The encodeURL is used to encode the url for session tracking in
>   forward and include mechanism. The encodeRedirectURL encodes the
>   specified URL for use in the sendRedirect method.
>
> The main difference between two is, the implementation of
>   encodeRedirectURL method includes the logic to determine whether the
>   session ID needs to be encoded in the URL in the case when you are
>   redirecting the URL to different context where the session information
>   is not required or invalid. The encodeURL method do not appent the
>   seesion id if the cookies are enabled. In addition to this
>   encodeRedirectURL do not append the session information if the URL is
>   redirected to the different context (web application). Because the
>   rules for making this determination can differ from those used to
>   decide whether to encode a normal link, this method is separete from
>   the encodeURL method.
>
> Hope this help you.
>
> Thanks
>
> Narendra Dhande